# Is there a use for an MDC even when all messages are signed?

Tags: encryption, hash, gnupg, pgp

I guess I have halfway grasped the concepts of PGP, and I've halfway understood the concept of the [Efail](https://efail.de) attack. However, I still don't understand whether such attacks would be possible (and an MDC would be needed) even if all messages had a signature. I have read several dozens of articles about Efail and MDC, but none of them mentioned how signatures come into play.

In my naive understanding, and without much details and over-simplified, and leaving out problems with headers and so on, the following happens when signing and encrypting a message e.g. with GnuPG:

- The message text is hashed.
- The hash is asymmetrically encrypted with the private PGP key of the sender.
- That encrypted hash becomes part of the message text.
- An encryption key for a symmetric encryption method is chosen.
- That symmetric encryption key is asymmetrically encrypted with the public PGP key of the recipient.
- The message is encrypted using the symmetric encryption key.
- The (asymmetrically encrypted) symmetric encryption key becomes part of the message.

In this scenario, i.e. when every message is signed, I can't understand how Efail attacks would work and why the MDC is recommended. After all, if anybody would tamper with the message during transmission, this would be detected when the signature would be verified. In my naive understanding, the following would happen upon reception:

- The symmetric encryption key is decrypted, using the private PGP key of the recipient.
- The whole message text is decrypted, using the symmetric encryption key.
- The hash of the message text is decrypted, using the public key of the sender.
- The decrypted message text is hashed by the recipient's client, and the obtained hash is compared with the hash from the previous step. If both hashes are the same, the message has not been modified.

Did I miss something? Is it possible to tamper with signed messages without the recipient knowing about it, provided the recipient's software **always** verifies the signature of received messages **before** doing anything with the message except saving it in decrypted form to disk for further usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an MDC, or in general, any sort of message authentication code, is not required when the entire message is signed with a trusted signature and the signature is verified first.  A secure and trusted digital signature is sufficient to prevent tampering over the data it signs.

However, there are many reasons why an MDC is still a good idea:

- The signer's key may not be present or available to verify the signature.
- The signer may not be trustworthy or their trustworthiness may be unknown.
- The signer and the party that encrypted the message may be different, and the signer may have received a tampered message.
- Most implementations scream very loudly if no MDC is present and some may fail altogether by default.

Generally, in cryptography and security, we prefer to have defense in depth.  There is little reason not to include an MDC, so we do it even if the message is to be signed, since this makes secure implementations easier and increases confidence that the message has not been altered.

Comment: Finally a clear statement! This is what I thought as well. Thank you very much, accepted and +1.